# Disable scrolling back up after a specific point

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for any specific javascript that might take the amount of viewport scrolled to then stop the user from scrolling back up above that point. Hiding elements after crossing over tagged divs only seems to drop the user at a lower point in the site.

This is an example of my code:

```js
const registerVideo = (bound, video) => {
    bound = document.querySelector(bound);
    video = document.querySelector(video);
    const scrollVideo = ()=>{
        if(video.duration) {
            const distanceFromTop = window.scrollY + bound.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            const rawPercentScrolled = (window.scrollY - distanceFromTop) / (bound.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
            const percentScrolled = Math.min(Math.max(rawPercentScrolled, 0), 1);
            
            video.currentTime = video.duration * percentScrolled;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(scrollVideo);
}


registerVideo("#bound-one", "#bound-one video");
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

#bound-one {
  background: #d0d8db;
}

.scroll-bound {
  height: 500vh;
}
.scroll-bound .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.scroll-bound video {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
    
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet kielbasa pastrami flank capicola, chicken spare ribs frankfurter t-bone meatloaf pork belly chuck. Chislic brisket short ribs rump meatloaf turducken picanha sausage tenderloin. Tenderloin pancetta kevin landjaeger meatloaf boudin swine fatback biltong. Turkey pork loin ribeye, bresaola pancetta cow ground round ham hock meatloaf. Pig kielbasa chuck, pork belly chicken shank ham hock. Sausage shankle meatball salami capicola shank short loin pork picanha pig bacon boudin beef. Meatball shankle tongue, rump ham ham hock swine jowl ground round venison doner picanha corned beef.</p>

<p>Kevin pork chop beef burgdoggen, brisket hamburger tenderloin jowl pancetta tail kielbasa drumstick shoulder short loin flank. Burgdoggen shank filet mignon spare ribs pig turducken hamburger ham hock tenderloin drumstick. Pork alcatra porchetta hamburger, chislic corned beef ham hock prosciutto tail shank. Chicken andouille turducken leberkas, turkey venison pork chop frankfurter pig pork belly biltong sirloin jerky drumstick ham hock.</p>
    
    <div id="bound-one" class="scroll-bound">
        <div class="content">
            <p>WebM Video</p>
            <video width="600" muted preload>
                <source src="https://cdn.ananaspizza.de/file/malte-image-store/v9-webm.webm" type="video/webm">
                <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
      </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet kielbasa pastrami flank capicola, chicken spare ribs frankfurter t-bone meatloaf pork belly chuck. Chislic brisket short ribs rump meatloaf turducken picanha sausage tenderloin. Tenderloin pancetta kevin landjaeger meatloaf boudin swine fatback biltong. Turkey pork loin ribeye, bresaola pancetta cow ground round ham hock meatloaf. Pig kielbasa chuck, pork belly chicken shank ham hock. Sausage shankle meatball salami capicola shank short loin pork picanha pig bacon boudin beef. Meatball shankle tongue, rump ham ham hock swine jowl ground round venison doner picanha corned beef.</p>

<p>Kevin pork chop beef burgdoggen, brisket hamburger tenderloin jowl pancetta tail kielbasa drumstick shoulder short loin flank. Burgdoggen shank filet mignon spare ribs pig turducken hamburger ham hock tenderloin drumstick. Pork alcatra porchetta hamburger, chislic corned beef ham hock prosciutto tail shank. Chicken andouille turducken leberkas, turkey venison pork chop frankfurter pig pork belly biltong sirloin jerky drumstick ham hock.</p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you deliberately want to break a web page like that?

Comment: You can add a scroll event listener and scroll to your specific point whenever scroll decreases than that point.

Comment: @Andy The initial section is a video that plays on scroll using GSAP, leading into an intro section. The client doesn't want the user to be able to scrub back up through the video.

Comment: make that video sticky then (something like this: https://codepen.io/vmasto_1470672674/pen/KyyMwq)

Comment: @GrafiCode that's not what I'm after. The video sits at the top of the page and you can scroll through it frame by frame, then you essentially scroll out of that container to the next section of the page. I don't want the user to be able to scrub back through the video.

Comment: given this pen: https://codepen.io/graficodestudio/pen/gOeawVW?editors=1010 you want it to prevent scrolling up once the user passed the video container?

Comment: @GrafiCode yeah, essentially that! It's designed as a video intro with a scroll prompt for the user, but doesn't make sense for them to be able to navigate back through it.